# How to report JDBC URL from Context

Tags: java, scala, jdbc

I am trying to build a "meta" API endpoint that returns certain useful information for internal use. One of the fields I would like to get is a database URL.

In the context file it is given like this:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/mycon" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
        removeAbandoned="true" removeAbandonedTimeout="30" maxActive="8" maxIdle="4" maxWait="10000"
        validationQuery="SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE 1+1"
        username="u" password="p" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        url="jdbc:mysql://my.url.com" />
```

I have some code (scala) that will return the information as a `DataSource` object:

```
val context = (new InitialContext).lookup("java:/comp/env").asInstanceOf[Context]
    val dataSource = context.lookup(s"jdbc/mycon").asInstanceOf[DataSource]
```

However I cannot figure out how to extract the URL from this. Is there a different class that I can cast the result to?

I tried using a BasicDataSource, but when I hit the endpoint I get the error message: `Error: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0 cannot be cast to org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource`

Answer (score 0):

A data source doesn't always have a JDBC URL. For example, it can be a driver specific data source that directly sets things like host, port and database, or it might be a data source that provides a connection pool and wraps the actual data source that has the connection information.

You could check if reflection of properties yields any useful information, but my guess would be that is shielded through the proxy class, and that it only exposes the `javax.sql.DataSource` API.